# Swing Frame setSize

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I've created a simple user interface in Swing but the setSize command does not appear to be working. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

```
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.*;

public class UserInterface1 {

    private JTextField outputArea = new JTextField();
    private JTextField errorReportArea = new JTextField();
    private JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();

    public UserInterface1() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fuel Station");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        outputArea.setEditable(false);
        errorReportArea.setEditable(false);

        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        contentPane.add(outputArea);
        contentPane.add(errorReportArea);
        contentPane.add(inputPanel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserInterface1 test = new UserInterface1();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Swing Frame setSize

The right answer to this is **don't do that!**

Even when we know the size of the **content** of a frame must be (e.g.) 500x500 px, we should not be guessing the size of the frame, which will vary by platform.

`pack()` knows how big to make the frame.  We don't, so we should use it.

- The size of the text fields can be specified using a font size and the number of columns.
- The right size for `inputPanel` can be determined from the content within it.

Answer (score -1):

Replace:

```
frame.setSize(500, 500);
```

by

```
frame.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 500));
```

Answer (score -2):

It's because pack() resizes the frame to fit the dimensions of its contents or the preferred size, so you can remove the pack() call, or add a preferred size with setPreferredSize() method

Comment: I feel this is the right answer to the wrong question, but had to -1 for *"so you can remove the pack() call, or add a preferred size with setPreferredSize() method"* either of which is bad practice.